# Postfix Send-Only SMTP Server domain name configuration

Tags: postfix, mail, smtp, mail-server, sendmail

I found 2 ways of sending mails from Linux/bash :

1. through a service , like sSMTP,  which implies using an external SMTP server, like gmail
2. through Postfix server, **which configures the Linux server to act as it's own SMTP server ( I think )**

I pretty much found documentation for how to configure each. From what I've seen then are security issues ( which I can't afford since I want to configure this in an IT production environment ) when using a sSMTP service, plus you have to have access to Internet. So this leaves us with Postfix server.

I know how to configure Postfix, except for the domain part. When you first configure this, it asks you for a domain name ( like `example.com` ). I don't know where to get this. **Don't you have to buy a domain ? or should I ask my IT department if they have one so I can use it ? or I can just type anything like `domain.com`** . I want to configure this on a Linux server. On the other hand , I have another Linux server on another network , which has Postfix server configured, so you can send mails , with the following config. file :

```
cat /etc/postfix/main.cf | grep -v "^#" | grep -v "^$"
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = server2.backup
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks = 168*.0/28, 127.0.0.0/8,localhost
relayhost = [10.*]:25
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases


debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
```

I modified the IP adresses with a * for security purposes. **What domain was configured here on Postfix ?** I just see here `localhost.$mydomain`, but this doesn't tell me anything. Thank your so much for your patience.

note 1: I found out server 2 uses a relay server in order to send mails, I still don't know what is the domain name it has

Comment: Ask your IT department if they have a **SMTP Relay** server available.  If they do, the simple option is using `ssmtp` (personally, I use `msmtp`) configured to point at the relay server

Comment: Are you trying to send emails internally (on a closed network) or to the Internet?

Comment: i want to send mails inside the network, basically, i want to send mail to the host from where i am using putty to connect to the server.

Comment: @AlexP it is a common convention to use `.localdomain` as a domain for an internal network with no connection to the Internet. Usually mail servers like Postfix are installed preconfigured with this. Actually, Postfix needs this setting mostly for **receiving** emails, not for sending them. BTW. You don't need to have Internet connection to use ssmtp or msmtp. That "external server" those applications are using may be as well another server in your network.

Comment: @AlexP also ask your IT department if they already use some domain name for such internal purposes - if yes, then use the same.

Comment: my question is, can't I use some linux commands to find out the domain name of the machine ? like nslookup or something ? and then use that domain in the configuration, what do you mean by .localdomain ? I just want to configure the machine only to send mails. Can I then use any name as domain name ?

Comment: I found out that there is no SMTP relay server to use as external, can I configure Postifx to send mails without an external SMTP relay ?

Comment: Are you sure this is not an xy problem? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: no, I was very specific about what I wanted to know, check bolded statements in question

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure if I correctly understood what you are trying to achieve and what exactly the problem is but for now I'm assuming you want to use Postfix on `server2.backup` to deliver mail to a mailserver running on `putty-server`.

You don't need a lot of configuration to achieve this:

```
# myorigin = <sending domain>
myhostname = server2.backup
relayhost = <putty-server's IP>
```

Set `myorigin` to whatever domain you want as default in your 'from' email address, e.g. `my-personal-domain.com` or `whitehouse.gov`. You can omit it if you want to send from `server2.backup`.

You need to set relayhost to the IP of `putty-server` if there is no matching MX record for the domain you are sending mail to. If you want to send mail to multiple servers, check [postfix' transport map](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) setting.

That's it. Make sure `putty-server` accepts mails from `server2.backup`'s ip(-range), e.g. by adding it to [`mynetworks`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks) on `putty-server`.

If this does not help you, update your question with

1. the output of `lsb_release -a` or `cat /etc/os-release`,
2. the output of `postconf mail_version`,
3. the output of `comm -23 <(postconf -n) <(postconf -d)`,
4. relevant log lines from `server2.backup` (`/var/log/mail.log) and
5. relevant log lines from `putty-server`.

Comment: No, it's simpler than this, I just want to configure Postfix on a Linux server as send-only SMTP server, I just want to be able to send mails from the server within the organization/network. But I don't know what domain name should I use, when it asks me to configure it. I don't know where I should take it from or should I just type anything. server2,back-up is just an example from another network, that has Postfix configured, and I tried to look in the configuration file to see what domain name it used, just to see if it a registered domain, or just made up name. Makes sense now ?

Comment: please check also the bolded questions, to see what I need

Comment: You can use whatever domain you want to send your mails from (@example.com, firstmanonmars.com) but you should probably use a domain that you own and that the relay server that `putty-server` is configured to use allows.

Comment: ok, thank you very much